# How to create a shortcode to print specific values stored in a post meta array?

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, post-meta

i am having problems printing a specific value stored in a post-meta array in a WordPress loop created by a Visual Composer Grid Builder, thru a shortcode (i also tried the grid builder Custom Field, but wasn't able to find ANY examples).

I tried adding this shortcode in functions.php:

```
function dmc_prezzo()
{
$postid = get_the_ID(); // get id from post in loop
$meta_data = get_post_meta($postid,'listing_options'); // select array
return $meta_data['price:value'] . ' ' . $meta_data['price:original']; // extract keys
}
add_shortcode('dmcprezzo', 'dmc_prezzo');  //usage [dmcprezzo]
```

I then added the shortcode to the text-field in the VC Grid template **but it is outputting nothing!**

Here is the target post meta array, extracted from a post, using DPM plugin:

```
    listing_options: s:349:"a:8:{s:5:"price";a:2:{s:5:"value";s:5:"17300";s:8:"original";s:5:"19800";}s:17:"custom_tax_inside";s:0:"";s:15:"custom_tax_page";s:0:"";s:8:"city_mpg";a:1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"5.7";}s:11:"highway_mpg";a:1:{s:5:"value";s:3:"4.6";}s:12:"custom_badge";s:7:"Venduta";s:5:"video";s:43:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBCOAumh6aI";s:10:"short_desc";s:0:"";}";
```

I can see that the variable containing the array is called `$listing_options` but i do not know to set the code right.

The values in which i am interested are the price:value and price:original found in the beginning of the array:

```
s:349:"a:8:{s:5:"price";a:2:{s:5:"value";s:5:"17300";s:8:"original";s:5:"19800";}
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the output of your array, when unserialized:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [price] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 17300
                    [original] => 19800
                )

            [custom_tax_inside] => 
            [custom_tax_page] => 
            [city_mpg] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 5.7
                )

            [highway_mpg] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 4.6
                )

            [custom_badge] => Venduta
            [video] => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBCOAumh6aI
            [short_desc] => 
        )

)
```

So, to access the price, you have to change your shortcode to this:

```
function dmc_prezzo() {
    $postid = get_the_ID(); // get id from post in loop
    $meta_data = get_post_meta($postid,'listing_options'); // select array
    return $meta_data['listing_options']['price']['value'] . ' ' . $meta_data['listing_options']['price']['original']; // extract keys
}
add_shortcode('dmcprezzo', 'dmc_prezzo');  //usage [dmcprezzo]
```

It would be better if you've posted the entire serialized data, I'm not sure if it's not nested.